# groovy: create a list of values with all strings

Tags: list, dictionary, groovy

I am trying to iterate through a map and create a new map value. The below is the input

```
def map = [[name: 'hello', email: ['on', 'off'] ], [ name: 'bye', email: ['abc', 'xyz']]]
```

I want the resulting data to be like:

```
[hello: ['on', 'off'], bye: ['abc', 'xyz']]
```

The code I have right now -

```
result = [:]
map.each { key ->
  result[random] = key.email.each {random ->
            "$random"
        }   
    }
return result
```

The above code returns

`[hello: [on, off], bye: [abc, xyz]]`

As you can see from above, the quotes from `on`, `off` and `abc`, `xyz` have disappeared, which is causing problems for me when i am trying to do checks on the list value `[on, off]`

Comment: I don't know how the above code would have worked! Maybe you haven't pasted the whole thing. I have added a working one below.

Answer (score 1):

It should not matter. If you see the result in Groovy console, they are still `String`.

Below should be sufficient:

```
map.collectEntries {
    [ it.name, it.email ]
}
```

If you still need the single quotes to create a `GString` instead of a `String`, then below tweak would be required:

```
map.collectEntries {
    [ it.name, it.email.collect { "'$it'" } ]
}
```

I personally do not see any reasoning behind doing the later way. BTW, `map` is not a `Map`, it is a `List`, you can rename it to avoid unnecessary confusions.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to a json object and then everything will have quotes

Answer (score 0):

This does it. There should/may be a groovier way though.

```
def listOfMaps = [[name: 'hello', email: ['on', 'off'] ], [ name: 'bye', email: ['abc', 'xyz']]]
def result = [:]
listOfMaps.each { map ->  
   def list = map.collect { k, v ->
      v
   }
  result[list[0]] = ["'${list[1][0]}'", "'${list[1][1]}'"]
}
println result
```

Comment: Or, you can replace the `list` object with `def list = map.collect { (it.value) }`